# Hitting SugarCRM API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sugarcrm

I am trying to hit the SUGARCRM API in order to get the session ID, but am receiving "result: null" when consoling result, and the same when consoling for an error. Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
var api_url = "https://***/service/v4_1/rest.php";
var user_name = "***";    //SugarCRM username
var password = "***";    //SugarCRM password
var request = require('request')

var params = {
   user_auth:{
     user_name:user_name,
     password:password,
     encryption:'PLAIN'
   },
   application_name: 'SugarCRM RestAPI Example' 
}
var restData = JSON.stringify(params);

request({
   type: "GET",
   url: api_url,
   data: {
     method: "login",
     input_type: "JSON",
     response_type: "JSON",
     rest_data: restData
   },
   dataType:"jsonp"},
   function(result) {console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));},
   function() {console.log("failed");})
```

Comment: encryption:'PLAIN' should pose a problem. Try using md5 for password encryption

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: I mean the password as md5 hash. I never needed the setting encryption in user_auth. Do you see something in the sugar log in debug level or the webservers access log?